# Jquery event that echos class

Tags: jquery

I need jQuery to echo out some data on a draggable image. I'm able to call up the location of the image relative to the window. I added event.target.nodename to the text that echos out but it only returns the html tag the image is in. This is all well and good, but because I'm using a while loop to produce several images I can't tell which event.target.nodename is referencing which image. Here is a sample of the jQuery code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $(function() 
 {
 $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(
 {
  stop: function(event,ui)

    {

    var Stoppos = $(this).position();

    $(".location").text("STOP: \nLeft: "+ Stoppos.left + "\nTop: " + Stoppos.top + 

    event.target.nodeName);

    }

 }
 );

 $(".droppable").droppable();

 });
 });
```

Note: Each image the while loop produces a unique class so there isn't a problem when it comes to identifying each image based on the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(event.target).class()` instead of `event.target.nodeName` should get you the class of the image